# Is there a TPM adapter for motherboards with no TPM header?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, usb-3, tpm, windows-11

OK,... So I have a motherboard that is a bit old, meaning, I just do not have the funds to upgrade it, the Processor, and RAM to something comparable AND have the TPM SPI module interface pins.

So my question basically boils down to, is there a USB3 adapter or a PCIe gen 3 adapter?

I know based on the accepted answer from this post, [USB-based external TPM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659491/usb-based-external-tpm) that a system that has a processor and/or motherboard that is not on the Microsoft Windows 11 HCL, most likely **NOT** support Windows 11. Or replace the *appraiserres.dll* file on the Windows 11 ISO with the one from Windows 10. Personally, I really do not care if it's not supported or recommended, I need to get Windows 11 up and running in a stable manner and replacing a DLL I'm really not familiar with, well, I really am not keen on that idea.

Here is my question about this on Tom's Hardware:
[Tom's Hardware Forum Post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/is-there-a-tpm-adapter-for-motherboards-with-no-tpm-header.3726026/)

In the course of researching this problem, I have literally tried everything I can think of to find a suitable result/answer. I'm even willing to do some soldering work to marry the TPM to a USB3 header.

Comment: All processors that support Windows 11 support fTPM

Comment: Replacing appraiserres.dll is your only hope of running Windows 11 on your device. While your system will run Windows 11 without TPM 2.0 support, it will be unsupported state, which likely means you won’t receive Windows Updates.  There likely will be a workaround to that state given enough time. Even if there is a USB TPM product you won’t change the fact your processor isn’t on the list of supported processors.  If your processor is on that list then it supports fTPM

Comment: You can always bypass the whole installer, appraiserres and all, and manually install Windows using DISM.

Comment: I need to get Windows 11 up and running in a stable manner  ...... Without TPM and also older generation of CPU Windows 11 will likely not be stable (if it runs at all). If you accept the risk of reinstalling Windows you can join the Windows Insider program and try it out.

Comment: @John - The channel where the compatibility check is disabled is an extremely unstable channel.

Comment: True but without TPM, I think production Windows 11 will not work well.  Microsoft seems determined not to let Windows 11 work on old hardware.

Answer (score 1):

So why not just install Windows 11 and tell it to ignore the system requirements. The OS will likely run fine if the hardware is fast enough without a TPM chip anyway.

Force Windows 11 install was developed by JosephM101 on GitHub. It'll create you a bootable ISO image that bypasses the system requirement check for CPU and TPM.
https://github.com/JosephM101/Force-Windows-11-Install/blob/main/docs/UUPDump-Tutorial.md

There are multiple other ways to do this as well. What does the TPM really do for Windows 11 that it critical for you use anyway?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).